# Defining stochastic process at $t=0$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

I have the following process:
$$
Z_t=\frac{1}{t}\Big(\frac{X^2_t}{\sigma^2_X}-\frac{Y^2_t}{\sigma^2_Y})+2 \Big(\frac{\mu_X}{\sigma^2_X}X_t-\frac{\mu_Y}{\sigma^2_Y}Y_t\Big)+\Big(\frac{\mu^2_X}{\sigma^2_X}-\frac{\mu^2_Y}{\sigma^2_Y}\Big)t
$$
where the processes $X_t$ and $Y_t$ are given by
$$
dX_t=\mu_X dt+\sigma_X dB_t
$$
$$
dY_t=\mu_Y dt+\sigma_Y dB_t
$$
where $B_t$ is a standard Brownian motion and the $\mu$'s and $\sigma$'s are constants. Is there a way to define $Z_0$? If I can show that $Z_t$ converges in probability toward a random variable $\hat Z_0$, can I define $Z_0=\hat Z_0$?

As suggested in the comment, I applied Ito's lemma to the first term and got:
$$
d\Big(\frac{1}{t}\Big(\frac{X^2_t}{\sigma^2_X}-\frac{Y^2_t}{\sigma^2_Y}\Big)\Big)=\Bigg(-\frac{1}{t^2}\Big(\frac{X^2_t}{\sigma^2_X}-\frac{Y^2_t}{\sigma^2_Y}\Big)+\frac{2}{t}\Big(\frac{\mu_X}{\sigma^2_X}X_t-\frac{\mu_Y}{\sigma^2_Y}Y_t\Big)\Bigg)dt+\frac{2}{t}\Big( \frac{X_t}{\sigma_X}-\frac{Y_t}{\sigma_Y}\Big)dB_t
$$
It seems that neither $dt$ nor $dB_t$ coefficients of the above process go to zero as $t$ approaches zero (since their means do not go to zero).

Comment: Of course you can define your stochastic process however you want, but I feel the question should rather be: 'Will my process still have nice properties (e.g. continuous sample paths) if I define it that way?'. I didn't carry out the calculation but it seems to me that in your case this should be true, since $X_t$ and $Y_t$ are relatively simple diffusions driven by the *same* brownian motion. Try to apply Itôs Lemma to $X_t^2$ and $Y_t^2$ to get an explicit dependance of your first term on $B_t$. Then show that This term tends to $0$ faster then linearily. (which would imply the claim.)

Comment: Agree with the above. But does such a limit even exist here?

Comment: I think @fesman is correct, please see my calculation I just added to my question.